# ASP.Net add item to listbox without posting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I am trying to add items to a listbox. I have a textbox and a button and when the user enters something into the textbox and hits add, I want to insert a new item the listbox without the page refreshing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">

                    <asp:Label ID="empid" runat="server" Text="Employee ID" CssClass="label-default label "></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeID" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddEmp" runat="server" Text="Add Emp" CssClass="btn btn-primary top-buffer" Width="100%" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveEmp" runat="server" Text="Remove Emp" CssClass="btn btn-danger top-buffer" Width="100%" />
                    </div>

                    <asp:ListBox ID="listEmps" runat="server"
                        CssClass="top-buffer add-height"
                        Width="100%"
                        ValidationGroup="req"></asp:ListBox>

                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is my button click event

```
Protected Sub btnAddEmp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddEmp.Click
 If Not IsPostBack() Then

    If listEmps.Items.Count = 0 Then
        listEmps.Items.Add(txtEmployeeID.Text)
    Else

        'check list to see if employee already exists
        For i = listEmps.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If RTrim(txtEmployeeID.Text) = RTrim(listEmps.Items(i).ToString) Then

                'employee already exists within list
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Employee ID " & txtEmployeeID.Text.Trim & " has already been added. ')</script>")

                txtEmployeeID.Text = ""
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        'add to list
        listEmps.Items.Add(txtEmployeeID.Text)
    End If

 End If
End Sub
```

How can I properly add items to a listbox without refreshing the page?

Comment: What about this isn't working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @zgood No errors, I hit the add button and nothing happens..

Comment: Have you tried removing the `If Not IsPostBack()` check? Typically this only used on the `Page_Load` event. The button click event should be asynchronous because it's in an `UpdatePanel`. But I don't think this is your problem...

Comment: @zgood I just removed it and it worked....lol however my "message box" work around doesn't work.. lol but I suppose that is another question.

Comment: Ok I will make an answer for this question then. For your message box I think you may want to look at `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `Response.Write` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @zgood Thanks, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `If Not IsPostBack() Then` check in your button click event. The `IsPostBack()` is typically only used for the `Page_Load` event. Since your button is contained in an `UpdatePanel` the click event should be asynchronous and won't cause a postback.